# Pattern matching a bitstring using pin operator in Elixir

Tags: elixir, pattern-matching, bitstring

```
# Erlang/OTP 24, Elixir 1.12.3

bmp_signature = <<66, 77>>
#=> "BM"

<<^bmp_signature, _::binary>> = <<66, 77, 30, 0>>
#=> ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: <<66, 77, 30, 0>>
```

Why is this happening?

In short, I'd like to pattern match bitstrings in a cycle, rather than writing method definitions by hand. So instead of this:

```
@bmp_signature <<66, 77>>
…

def type(<<@bmp_signature, _::binary>>), do: :bmp
…
```

…something like this:

```
@signatures %{
  "bmp" => <<66, 77>>,
  …
}

def detect_type(file) do
  find_value_func = fn {extension, signature} ->
    case file do
      <<^signature, _::binary>> -> extension
      _ -> false
    end
  end

  Enum.find_value(@signatures, find_value_func)
end
```

Is this solvable without metaprogramming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off. Remember that the pin operator `^` pins only a single value.  In your example, you were trying to pin it to 2 values.

So if the thing you are trying to match on is a binary with 2 values that you are aware of, then you would need to pin both of them, e.g.

```
iex> <<bmp_sig1, bmp_sig2>> = <<66, 77>>
iex> <<^bmp_sig1, ^bmp_sig2, rest::binary>> = <<66, 77, 88, 23, 44, 89>>
<<66, 77, 88, 23, 44, 89>>
iex> rest
<<88, 23, 44, 89>>
```

The binary syntax `<<>>` isn't the only way to do this -- you can accomplish the same with regular strings (assuming the values are in fact strings):

```
iex> x = "apple"
"apple"
iex> "ap" <> rest = x
"apple"
iex> rest
"ple"
```

The rub here is that you can't *pin* a prefix because you need a *literal* value in order to do the match. This is because the length of the binary isn't known beforehand.

If you know your "signatures" always have 2, 3, or 4 characters, you can code your variables to be pinned appropriately.  However, if you must deal with a an unknown length, then you'd probably need to rely on something more like a regular expression or `String.starts_with?/2` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Seems like Erlang's match/2 method in the binary module does the job.

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept the answer, or if you can share a link to match/2 I can update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Asking whether this is doable without metaprogramming is like asking to solve a list reverse without both `Enum` module and recursion.

In [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), there *is* metaprogramming to solve exactly this kind of task. It makes the code clean, succinct, and manageable.

```elixir
defmodule Type do
  @signatures %{
    bmp: <<66, 77>>
  }

  Enum.each(@signatures, fn {name, bom} ->
    def detect(<<unquote(bom), _::binary>>), do: unquote(name)
  end)
  def detect(_), do: nil
end

Type.detect(<<66, 77, 30, 0>>)
#⇒ :bmp
Type.detect(<<66, 30, 0>>)
#⇒ nil
```

---

It’s still can be done in an ugly not idiomatic way without metaprogramming, though.

```elixir
defmodule Type do
  @signatures [
    {<<66, 77>>, :bmp},
    {<<77, 66>>, :pmb}
  ]
  
  def detect(signature, candidates \\ @signatures) do
    for <<c <- signature>>, reduce: @signatures do
      acc -> 
        Enum.reduce(acc, [], fn
          {"", name}, acc -> [{"", name} | acc]
          {<<^c, rest::binary>>, name}, acc -> [{rest, name} | acc]
          _, acc -> acc
        end)
    end
  end
end

case Type.detect(<<66, 77, 30, 0>>) do
  [{"", type}] -> {:ok, type}
  [] -> {:error, :none}
  [few] -> {:error, few: few}
end
#⇒ {:ok, :bmp}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Regarding the metaprogramming solution. So dynamically defining a method for every signature is the "Elixir way"? What if there was 100500 signatures, would it still be efficient?
I also believe you didn't mean defining `def detect(_), do: nil` for _every_ signature. As well as you didn't mean that your code is supposed to return different results for the same input:
`Type.detect(<<66, 77, 30, 0>>) #⇒ :bmp Type.detect(<<66, 77, 30, 0>>) #⇒ nil`

Comment: `def detect(_), do: nil` fixed, thanks for pointing this out. “What if there was 100500 signatures”—requires a benchmark, but those are files signatures. There won’t be 100500.

Answer (score -1):

Erlang's [:binary.match/2](https://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#match-2) is the right tool for the job:

```rb
defmodule Type do
  @signatures [
    {"bmp", <<66, 77>>},
    {"jpg", <<255, 216, 255>>},
  ]

  def detect(file_binary) do
    find_value_func = fn {extension, signature} ->
      case :binary.match(file_binary, signature) do
        {0, _} -> extension
        _ -> nil
      end
    end

    Enum.find_value(@signatures, find_value_func)
  end
end

Type.detect(<<66, 77, 0, 0>>) #=> "bmp"
Type.detect(<<55, 66, 0, 0>>) #=> nil
Type.detect(<<255, 216, 255, 0>>) #=> "jpg"
```

A big thank you goes to @Everett for his advice to look elsewhere.

Comment: Using a regular expression here is an absolute anti-pattern.

Comment: I wonder how's using Erlang's **binary** library that was specifically designed for this purpose is an anti-pattern, and how is this related to regular expressions? Here's a quote from the docs:
"This module contains functions for manipulating byte-oriented binaries. Although the majority of functions could be provided using bit-syntax, the functions in this library are highly optimized and are expected to either execute faster or consume less memory, or both, than a counterpart written in pure Erlang."